# Stop finder using cover flow in icon view

Tags: finder, sort

I am using Mac OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion and one of the finder features that really annoys me is that when i try to sort files by 'Date Created' in icon view it separates them into sections such as 'Yesterday', 'Previous 7 Days' etc. and uses a cover flow like effect to browse through them. These sections mean that to browse i have to scroll *along* each section then  move *down* to the next and scroll along that one.

Is there any way to stop finder from using this feature?

Thanks in advance, Ben.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click in the folder you have the problem.
2. Select Arrange by > None.
3. Right click again and select Clean up by > Date Created.

Comment: Thank you! Will this automatically sort the files as i add more?

Comment: Yep. It will. You’re welcome.