# Disable cover flow in 10.8 Mavericks

Tags: macos, finder

I'm annoyed that when I arrange a folder "by Kind" while in Icon View, each section is a single line with a cover flow collapsing all the icons that don't fit in the line.

(I very rarely use icon view, but the folder in question contains a mix of images, GIMP files the images were generated from, and a great many subfolders; I'd like to be able to quickly look at the icons for my png  images.)

Is there any way I can get a grid view of the files sorted by kind, or better yet by type (e.g. separate .png and .xcf files.)?

(The results from finding *.png are perfect layout (not shown), but mix in images from folders, which does not serve my purposes.)

Arrange By: None

Good:  Grid arrangement.  Bad: files and folders mixed.

[image: finder window arranged by none]

Arrange By: Kind

Good: Files and folders separated.  Bad: most icons hidden in cover flow scroll area.

[image]

This question has been asked before on other versions of OS X, but the solutions given there (arrange by none and then clean up by kind) don't work for me, as "Clean up by" is grayed out on the top menu and completely absent from the context menu.

Ref:
[Stop finder using cover flow in icon view](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64457/stop-finder-using-cover-flow-in-icon-view)

[Remove horizontal scrolling in finder with big thumbnail view](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106513/remove-horizontal-scrolling-in-finder-with-big-thumbnail-view)

As per the accepted answer below, the solution was:
1. Arrange By: None
2. Pull up the options with Command-J or Control-click on the window
3. Sort By Kind

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Arrange By set to None, Show View Options (⌘J) and choose Sort By: Kind.

Comment: Nope, after Arrange By None, Clean Up By is still greyed out.  I edited my question to (hopefully) make that clearer.

Comment: @arp Maybe a sort by is in place, see edit

Comment: Ah ha!  Your edited answer got me what I wanted!  And as an added bonus, "Sort by Kind" in the options popup does not use the same criteria as "Arrange by Kind", but sorts the .xcf and .png files separately.